# Ubuntu Firefox: Scrollbar is not visible while reading pdf

Tags: firefox, pdf, scrollbar

While reading pdf in Ubuntu Firefox browser, scrollbar is not visible.  Since it is not visible, it is difficult to scroll from current location.  If I try to click invisible scrollbar, current reading location is lost.

**1) Default behavior:** Scroll bar is not visible.
(even when mouse hovers over scrollbar)
[image]

**2) Click on invisible scrollbar.** It appears where we click. Previous reading location is lost.
[image]

**3) Switch to other window.**  Scrollbar appears !!!
[image]

Anyway I can use document viewer for reading pdf.  However I read some online pdfs temporarily without storing them.  Please let me know if this trivial point can be avoided.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is Firefox issue, and you should report bug to Mozilla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue seems to be fixed by Firefox 67.0.4 in Ubuntu 19.04. It was probably an [issue](https://github.com/ubuntu/yaru/issues/1096) on the Yaru theme on Ubuntu 18.10.